# how to add bootstrap responsive features to my navigation without changing my styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-design

I'm working on a navigation and I want to add bootstrap responsive feature to it, but without changing my original styling, like color, height and etc. appreciate if any one can help me on this.

below is the navigation mark up.

```
    <header id="pageHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="navMain">
                <ul id="navContainer">
                    <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

and this is the styling I have used.

```
#pageHeader{
  background-color: rgb(250,210,0);
  width: 100%;
}
/* 3.2. Logo Styling */
#logoTop{
  float:left;
}
/* 3.3. Main Navigation Styling */ 
#navMain{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: 84px 10px 21px 10px;
}
ul#navContainer{
  display: block;
  position: inherit;
}
#navMain ul li{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-image: none;
}
#navMain ul li a{
  color: rgb(99,99,99);
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 3px 10px 12px;
  font-family: "nexa_500", Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  transition: color ease 0.7s;
}
#navMain li a:hover,
#navMain li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(33,33,33);
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.7s;
  transition: color ease 0.7s;
}
#navMain ul li a.selected{
  color: rgb(33,33,33);
}
```

Comment: Rather than goin the bootstrap way for this , I ll advise you to write specific media queries for the nav you in place and it will solve the purpose

Comment: thank you. any tips how to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write queries like the following :

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

   position:fixed;
   margin-top:10px;

    }
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
   write query here as well

          }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    write query  here as well
      }
```

Comment: @shan can you please select it as answer